# Two way binding using interface

Tags: angular, two-way-binding

I have the following interface:

```
 export interface IUserData 
{
  Username: string;
  Email: string;
  Password: string;
}
```

And I want to bind it's properties to inputs like this:

```
<input [(value)]="userCredentials.Password">
```

Can I achieve that without having additional fields for each property in my component.ts?
Maybe like this:

```
    @Input() userCredentials: IUserData =
    {
      Username:"",
      Email:"@",
      Password:""
    };

    @Output() userCredentialsChange = new EventEmitter();
```

Comment: I did and userCredentials has initial values when i submit

Comment: I noticed you use input, maybe you can bind the entire form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input [(ngModel)]="userCredentials.Password">
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4vr4nc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts